# Error when creating Grails project using GGTS

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I just downloaded GGTS and Grails. When I was trying to create a Grails project via the button "CREATE GRAILS PROJECT" on the dash board, it shows this error after a while:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'test'.org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Number;
```

I am using 64-bit Windows 7, with JDK 1.7.0 build 51 (64-bit), Grails 2.4.0, and GGTS 3.5.1 with Eclipse 4.3.2. Also, the Groovy Compiler version is 2.1.8.

The project can still be built, but with an error alert whenever I tried the run it. And it runs fine (I didn't add anything, it just shows the welcome page fine). I can build a project with `grails create-app` in cmd.

Comment: BTW, I downloaded a 64-bit version of GGTS as well. And I installed Grails manually, didn't use the one comes with GGTS.

Comment: Did you add that grails instance to your Eclipse runtime through the Grails preferences page?  Are you using the correct version of groovy for your grails version?

Comment: I added Grails to Eclipse. I am using Grails 2.4 and Groovy 2.1.8. I don't know if they are compatible. And I don't know where to download a newer version of Groovy.

Comment: Also, I noticed that under "X:\Grails\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars", I have Groovy 2.3.1. How should I tell GGTS to use this Groovy compiler instead of the built-in one?

Comment: Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler. Choose the proper groovy version for your grails install. You can have one groovy compiler per Eclipse instance.

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to add another groovy there, but I downloaded one in extension page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like I found the problem. The Groovy compiler comes with GGTS is not compatible with Grails I installed manually. Go to Manage Extensions in dash board, search for Groovy, and then install Groovy 2.3. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the GGTS zip file, you should unblock the zip file **before** extracting out. This should solve your problem. Unblocking at the zip file would ensure all executables after the extraction would be unblocked too.